# Can read/write/delete OS files with plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to read, write, delete OS files with PL/pgSQL?

Can I run OS commands?

I've seen some examples that you can copy files like CSV but can you read/write/delete OS files? Can you execute OS commands?

Comment: You can read/write files if the user account running postgres has the appropriate permissions on those files. Executing OS commands? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

PL/pgSQL is a trusted language and as such does not allow access to server resources, let alone running OS commands.

[Explanation of "trusted language"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang-install.html)

> The optional key word TRUSTED specifies that the language does not grant access to data that the user would not otherwise have. Trusted languages are designed for ordinary database users (those without superuser privilege) and allows them to safely create functions and procedures. Since PL functions are executed inside the database server, the TRUSTED flag should only be given for languages that do not allow access to database server internals or the file system

---

There are some some [SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) available that enable roles with superuser privilege to *read* files on the server - but that is independent of PL/pgSQL.

If you do want to open up your database server for all kind of attacks, use a non-trusted language, like [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) or if you are really adventurous [PL/sh](https://github.com/petere/plsh)

Comment: Thank you very much. The trusted part comfused me.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has some [functions to read files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) in the data directory: `pg_read_file` and `pg_read_binary_file`

The [“adminpack” extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/adminpack.html) has a function to write files: `pg_file_write`

Perhaps you can abuse [`COPY ... TO PROGRAM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to run code on the server.

But the smart thing to do is to write a function in PL/PerlU or PL/Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I really appreciate it but user a_horse_with_no_name answered first.

Comment: Sure. I posted it nonetheless since I though I had some slightly different things to share.